# Pandas line break on each comma separated list item when exporting to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am using the following code using Pandas to export some data to Excel. The data is nothing but a List of some type. In this list, one of the items is a list again (Location). Here is a screenshot (when I expand one of the list items it's as follows) :

[image: list item expanded]

Now using Pandas when I export the data to xlst, see the screenshot below. All the locations are being exported to one line with comma separated. Is there a way to make the row bigger for those columns that are comma separated adding a line break after the comma?

[image: issue]

For instance in the Location column when I open I want to see something like:

```
          EcoSystem    Package   ...             Location
 
First Row                                      Core\\ATF\\.....,
                                            Core\\CoreServer\\....,
                                            EchoNET\\UI\\.....
```

Here is the code I have to export the data. Note the values parameter which is a list of some type that contains the `Location` list.

```
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
   
   #Write to CSV in xlsx format with indentation.
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
   df = df.set_axis(df.index*2 + 1).reindex(range(len(df)*2)) #Create a blank row after every row.

   with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:
       df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

   workbook  = writer.book
   worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
   #font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})
   header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': False,
        'border': False,
        'text_wrap': True})
   
   for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) the elements of each `"Location"` with a line return `"\n"`, then enlarge enough its column-width in Excel so then wrapping will be sufficiently visible. For the example, I choose 60 for the width but you can adjust it.

```
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
    df = df.set_axis(df.index*2 + 1).reindex(range(len(df)*2))

    # from ast import literal_eval # if needed
    # df["Location"] = df["Location"].apply(literal_eval)
    df["Location"] = df["Location"].str.join("\n")

    with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': False,
            'border': False,
            'text_wrap': True})

        for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

        twrap = workbook.add_format({"text_wrap": True})
        idx_location = df.columns.get_loc("Location")
        worksheet.set_column(idx_location, idx_location, 60, twrap)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all the comment `#Write to CSV in xlsx format` is non sense: CSV is a *text* format file aimed at data interchange and is no more related to Excel than to Pandas or Python or any other tool able to handle data consisting in rows and columns.

Then *All the locations are being exported to one line with comma separated.* is false too: the cell contains the string representation of a Python list (it is enclosed in square brackets). Which is no surprise because you asked Pandas to export a list.

A simple way is to pre-process the data. As it consists of a Python list, it would be probably better to process it outside of Pandas, but you failed to tell what is `values` is your code (a list of lists, a list of dicts, ...).

Anyway, it is easy to pre-process a dataframe column:

```
df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda ls: '\n'.join(ls))
```

This should be enough to replace the default representation with a sequence of items separated with newlines. But you might have to increase the height of the rows in the xlsx file...